# Transfer Data From Model To Controller - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having issue passing variable from model to controller. Here is my code.

```
<?php
class insert_model extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function form_insert($data)
    {
        // Inserting in Table(students) of Database(college)
       $this->db->insert('students', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

Controller : - insert_ctrl.php

```
<?php
class insert_ctrl extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('insert_model');
    }
    function index()
    {
        //Including validation library
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class=error>', '</div>');

        //Validating Name Field
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('dname', 'Username', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[15]');

        //Validating Email Field
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('demail', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');

        //Validating Mobile no. Field
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('dmobile', 'Mobile', 'required');

        //Validating Address Field
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('daddress', 'Address', 'required|min_length[10]|max_length[50]');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            $this->load->view('insert_view.php');
        }
        else{
            //Setting values for table columns
            $data = array(
                'Student_Name' => $this->input->post('dname'),
                'Student_Email' => $this->input->post('demail'),
                'Student_Mobile' => $this->input->post('dmobile'),
                'Student_Address' => $this->input->post('daddress')
            );
            //Transfering data to Model
            $this->load->model('insert_model', $data);
            $data['message'] = "Data Inserted Successfully";
            //Loading View
            $this->load->view('insert_view');
        }
    }
}
?>
```

[Error On XAMPP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKFsd.png)

Help Required. I have uploaded image of error on xampp. Help me. I have read other threads but can't getting it how to transfer data.

Comment: So line #40 is where?...

Comment: $this->load->model('insert_model', $data);

Comment: if you are using codeigniter 3 your controller and model names need to start with a capital:  Insert_model extends CI_Model Note that you load them and call them in lower case like you are doing now.

Answer (score 1):

The CodeIgniter documentation is your best friend, trust me. Make sure you understand what the parameters are expecting from you.

See the [Loading a Model section](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html#loading-a-model)

[image]

---

You are sending your `$data` array into the second parameter of the `model()` function. This is wrong, it expects a string if you wish to use that feature.

```
// WRONG
$this->load->model('insert_model', $data);
```

---

To fix your code, you must do this:

```
$this->load->model('insert_model'); // Load your model without trying to set parameter #2 unless you wish to rename the model
$this->insert_model->form_insert($data); // Call the function to insert your data
```

Comment: I have did it before... but the issue remains same. See these. http://imgur.com/a/k9D2p

Comment: That's a different issue, it's a completely different file and line number.